# ¿Como formatear cadena de texto e array?

Tags: javascript, csv

Buenas estoy trabajando con Javascript
Lo que estoy haciendo es subir un archivo csv para al momento de leerlo crear un array de objetos, ya lo tengo hecho el problema es como viene la informacion, ejemplo:
Al subir mi csv lo manda de esta manera

```
486245287,"LA EMPRESA, S.A. DE C.V.",JUAN PEREZ,2015,24/08/2003
123456123,"NOMBRE",PERSONA,2014,13/01/2002
```

para meterlo en el array hago esto:

```
var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
```

Asi me trae un array por cada columna o salto de linea

Ahora lo separo con un `split(',')` 
y me trae mis datos asi

```
0: "123456123"
1: "NOMBRE"
2: "PERSONA"
3: "2014"
4: "13/01/2002"
```

Que es correcto pero que pasa con mi primera columa? me ocasiona problemas por que en el nombre de la empresa tiene una coma entonces mi array ya no seria de 4 (como debería ser) sino de 5,
Espero me halla explicado mi problema

La información que necesito es asi:

```
0: "486245287"
1: "LA EMPRESA, S.A. DE C.V."
2: "JUAN PEREZ"
3: "2015"
4: "24/08/2003"
```

Lo que necesito esta separado por comas (,) al hacer el split me pone

```
0: "486245287"
1: "LA EMPRESA"
2: "S.A. DE C.V."
3: "JUAN PEREZ"
4: "2015"
5: "24/08/2003"
```

Como quiero que salga es como la primera, hice un replace de:

```
486245287,"LA EMPRESA, S.A. DE C.V.",JUAN PEREZ,2015,24/08/2003.replace(", "," ");
```

pero que pasa si en mi archivo hay 300 registros el replace creo que ya no me serviria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes primero formatear el texto de tu entrada, ya que los texto osea `string` en tu archivo están contenidos entre `" el texto "`, debe hacer un split al signo `"` y luego reemplazar las comas contenidas entre las comillas. Para tal caso ejecuta una lógica para detectar texto contenido entre comillas usando `split()`. Aquí una explicación:

```
    >> ' ESTO , DE "AQUI" , ES UN TEXTO Y "ESTO" TAMBIEN '
       // si ejecuto la funcion SPLIT('"') ,  
       // LOS TEXTO SE ENCONTRARAN EN LOS INDICES 1 Y 3 .. OSEA (N=1,N+2)

     //  [    0        *1          2          *3     4    ]
    >> ' ESTO , DE "AQUI" , ES UN TEXTO Y "ESTO" TAMBIEN '

    Otro ejemploe de:

     // [   0     *1 3  *2     4      *5    6   *7     8   *9 ]
    >> ' ESTO, "DE" "AQUI", ES UN "TEXTO" Y "ESTO" TAMBI"EN"'
```

Ahora tu código en javascript podría se este:

```js
var filecvs = '486245287,"LA EMPRESA, S.A. DE C.V.",JUAN PEREZ,2015,24/08/2003\n123456123,"NOMBRE",PERSONA,2014,13/01/2002';

var values = filecvs.split('\"')
var indexIsText = 1;
var Originaltextos = [];
values = values.map((value,index)=>{ // map crea un nuevo array
   if(index == indexIsText){ // si equivale a un index de texto
      while(value.indexOf(',') !== -1 ){ // mientra contenga comas 
        value = value.replace(',','.'); // reemplaza las comas
        indexIsText += 2;  // pasa a otro index de texto
      }
      Originaltextos.push(value);
   }
   return value;
})

var formatFile = values.join("")
var lineas = formatFile.split('\n')
lineas.forEach((linea)=>{
  let info = linea.split(',')
  console.log(info)
})
console.log(Originaltextos)
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, pero la información que necesito es la que esta con comas, edito mi pregunta

Comment: @JuanJose he actualizado la respuesta, mira el la variable `Originaltextos`

Answer (score 1):

Una solución simple es que reemplaces las comas que separan las columnas (las que no están entre comillas) por un separador diferente, por ejemplo un tabulador (`\t`). El siguiente ejemplo, usa expresiones regulares, `replace` y `split`

```js
var csv = `486245287,"LA EMPRESA, S.A. DE C.V.",JUAN PEREZ,2015,24/08/2003
123456123,"NOMBRE",PERSONA,2014,13/01/2002`;

var regex = /"[^"]+"|(\,)/g;
csv2 = csv.replace(regex, function(m, group1) {
    if (!group1) return m;
    else return '\t';
});
console.info(csv2.split('\t'))
```

Lo anterior es una adaptación de un ejemplo tomado de [una respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23667311/1595451) a [Regex to match all instances not inside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6462578/1595451)